# How to properly show one's friends in a graph if the number of friends is large

Tags: graphs

Say I want to show all of A's friends in the following form.But what to do when there're a lot of friends of A?And what's the name of this kind of graph?
[image]

**Edit:** For clarification, I want to represent a friend list in a graph as shown in the image and want to know if that's possible when the number of friends is large. I ask for the name of this kind of graph so that I can do a more specific google search. I'm also curious about which graph suits best if the above is not possible.

Comment: why do you make a graph for representing this?

Comment: @DimitraMiha Because boss likes this! Just for curiosity, what's best suited for this then?

Comment: What benefit does the boss think this infographic will have?

Comment: Mmm... Is this a UX question or a definition question? What're you trying to achieve here? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @theonlygusti Actually I don't know. Someone told me this is a must because boss likes this and I forgot to ask why as I was busy then. Maybe he didn't know either. But in my opinion if the number of friends is small this representation is better than a list.

Comment: @Majo0od See my edit.

Comment: You've come across a limitation of this kind of graph: it doesn't scale well. You can tell that to your boss. So you have to find additional techniques to compensate for that.

Comment: "a friend list in a graph "... if it's a list just show a list. The graph's only useful if you need to show extra info like possible links between the friends. And then it'll get messy anyways. In this case interactive filtering is usually your best bet, maybe just superimposed on top of the list.

Comment: How many levels of "depth" do you want? Only friends? Or friends of friends, or friends of friends of friends or ...

Answer (score 2):

It is simply called a graph

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)

> In graph theory, a graph is a structure amounting to a set of objects in which some pairs of the objects are in some sense "related".
>
> Typically, a graph is depicted in diagrammatic form as a set of dots for the vertices, joined by lines or curves for the edges.

More specifically you are looking for a social network graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network

Comment: I think a social network graph is different from this one as the former contains relationships between persons but the latter only contains who're friends of one person.

Comment: It is still a social network graph just one as you say that only contains people who're friends with one person

Answer (score 1):

You could call this type of infographic a network.

There is no way to get around the fact that it will quickly become busy and dense with a lot of friends, you would have to use another visualisation tool.

Ask your boss what they wanted to gain from this visualisation, and also ask them more generally why they feel they need one in the first place.

See if any other infographic would suffice.

Comment: "you would have to use another visualisation tool" / "See if any other infographic would suffice" - do you have any sugegstions?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica ask the boss why they want this graph. Then give them a better solution than the unscalable one the boss proposed. Obviously the better solution ("another visualisation tool"/"other infographic" as you quote me) depends on what the boss wants out of all of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a process called Clustering. [Here is an example used on Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering)

Basically elements are clustered depending on the current zoom level. When user zooms on a specific cluster, that same cluster gets divided in other lower level group.

Now, this only makes sense if A's friends can be grouped on categories like: location, age, gender, hobbies, etc... which I don't know if they are.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up with a solution like [this](http://skill-map.stuq.org/).

When the number of items is small, we show all of them.
[image]

When the number of items is large, we just show part of them and we scroll or touch the screen to see the others.
[image]

Even in this way, we can place only a limited number of items on the circle. But since only part of the circle is visible on the screen, we can replace the data when they are about to be visible if necessary.

For example, we have 100 items, and we place 20 of them on a circle, and only 5 of them are visible on the screen. At first we have items [1...20] on the circle and items [1...5] are visible. After we rotate 90deg, items [6...10] are visible. If we rotate 180deg again, items [16...20] are visible. Now we must replace items [1...15] to items [21...35] so that when we continue rotating we can see the right data.

Comment: Please accept your own answer. Doing so will help others who read this question in future, by clearly indicating which solution you cose.

Answer (score -1):

> And what's the name of this kind of graph?

These types of charts are caller **RADAR CHARTS**

[image]

> Say I want to show all of A's friends in the following form.But what
>   to do when there're a lot of friends of A?

THe only possible way is to do **grouping** or **categorizing** and you can either use a badge or follow the above example.

---

If you need any help regarding implementation you can look into

```
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart
```

Comment: From what you refer to, "a radar chart is a way of showing multiple data points and the variation between them". But I don't need to show the variation here.